# Can Khajiit become werewolves?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was just wondering because I'm not at that point in the game yet where you can become a werewolf, so I would like to know when I get there: can my Khajiit character become a werewolf, just like other races can?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can. I've become a werewolf with my first character, who was a Kahjit melee assassin.

Comment: "Is that fur, growing out of your ears" "...yes?"

Answer (score 7):

Yes, characters of any playable race can become a werewolf, including Argonians and Khajiits.

I myself have a werewolf Khajiit, and there is not any problem with this.

Answer (score -1):

you can become werewolf with kahjit race. I have done before

Comment: This answer does not add anything that is not already contained in the previous answers. If you have something new to add, then start your own answer, otherwise, you should just up-vote the best answer.

Comment: @ChargingPun you forgot to put the part about editing.